# Obtener resultado de json unificado

Tags: php, json, array

Hola tengo este array en php que siempre me imprime dos json separados como se muestra:

> {"result":"OK","numero":"20120305_001","codigo":"AA"}{"result":"OK","numero":"20120305_001","codigo":"BB"}

no se que le falte al arreglo  , desearia que imprimiera todo junto , justo como:

> {"result":"OK","numero":"20120305_001","codigo":"AA","numero":"20120305_001","codigo":"BB"}

Gracias de antemano.

```
global $varjson;

$response = '';

$query = "  SELECT numero, codigo FROM tabla WHERE i_ticket = '".$numero."' ";

$search = $varjson->runQuery( $query );

foreach ( $search as $row ) {

  $response['numero'.":".$row['numero'].','.'codigo'.':'."chk_".$row['codigo']] = '1';  

  $response = array(
             'result'        =>  'OK' ,
             'numero'           => $row['numero']  ,
             'codigo'           => $row['codigo']  ); 

  echo json_encode( $response ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$search = $varjson->runQuery( $query );

$result = array();

foreach ( $search as $row ) {

  $response['numero'.":".$row['numero'].','.'codigo'.':'."chk_".$row['codigo']] = '1';  

   $result = array(
                'result'        =>  'OK' ,
               'numero'         => $row['numero']  ,
               'codigo'         => $row['codigo']  ); 

    echo json_encode( $result ); 
    }
```

intenta de esta forma

Comment: Gracias por la atencion pero no me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Es interesante lo que quieres hacer Juan, pero solo queria comentarte que tengas cuidado ya que un JSON no permite tener 2 atributos con el mismo nombre

¿Lo que buscas seria algo asi?

```
[ 
      {"result":"OK","numero":"20120305_001","codigo":"AA"},
      {"result":"OK","numero":"20120305_001","codigo":"BB"} 
]
```

Por que de otro modo te regresaria este valor

```
{
    codigo: "BB"
    numero: "20120305_001"
    result: "OK"
}
```

Ya que te sobreescribiria numero y codigo por la segunda asignacion.

Comment: $response['numero'.":".$row['numero'].','.'codigo'.':'."chk_".$row['codigo']] = '1'; esta linea la  puse porque de aqui si me imprime el json unificado como lo he estado buscando  pero ahora estoy intentando con un array  push

Comment: no se bien la sintaxis pero en lugar de asignacion mejor deberias hacer un push al arreglo, algo asi, array_push( $response,result' =>  'OK' ,
             'numero'           => $row['numero']  ,
             'codigo'           => $row['codigo'] ); y saca el echo json_encode( $response ); del ciclo